# Using parameters in BackgroundWorker handlers

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, backgroundworker

For passing data to a `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` I use a separate wrapper class' instance:

```
MyParams mpar = new MyParams();
...
mpar.Par1 = par1val;
mpar.Par2 = par2val;
mpar.Par3 = par3val;
...
var worker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
worker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker1_DoWork);
worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
worker1.RunWorkerAsync(mpar);
```

Then I can use parameters of `mpar` instance in `worker1_DoWork`, operating in another thread.

```
void worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
      //here we use mpar.Par1, mpar.Par2 and so on
 }
```

In `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` we do some postactions in UI thread.

**My question is :** Can we use in `RunWorkerCompleted` handler the `mpar` instance, which worked just before in `DoWork` handler and can we be sure its values are the same it had in `DoWork`? If not, what is the correct approach for sharing parameters for various stages of `BackgroundWorker` operation?

```
void worker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            //Can we use the mpar instance here?
        }
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can assign the value of `e.Result` in `worker1_DoWork`

```
static void worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Do the work
    //...

    e.Result = new MyParams();
}
```

Then you can get it in the `worker1_RunWorkerCompleted` in `e.Result`.

If you need to pass additional result value and you don't want to put MyParams object in the `worker1_DoWork: e.Result` - then you can create a small class `ResultHolder` with `MyParams` and `MyResult` as properties and use that class to pass the result in `worker1_DoWork`

Comment: Thanks! Should I explicitly write the `mpar` into `e.Result` in the `worker1_DoWork`: `e.Result = mpar;`?

Comment: @rem yeah I think this is a recommended way.